# Hibernate late lazy loading in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, session, lazy-loading, connection-pooling

If I load a `City` object from DB using Hibernate session, and then using the same session which has not been used for an hour, if I do a `city.getCountry()` which should lazy load the `Country` object, I get an Exception (Connection marked as broken because of `SQLSTATE(08003)`). I got two general questions:

1. Is lazy loading just another new JDBC connection and totally
   independent connection under the hood?
2. What kind of parameters in hibernate connection pool configuration I
   need to tune to increase the timeout for these kind of situations?

I'm not using transactions.
I'm using HikariCP and my DB is Postgrsql.

Comment: Same Session as in same hibernate session?

Comment: Yes same hibernate session

Comment: IMHO .. Usually keeping a hibernate session for so long is an anti pattern.. Create a new session and try to access from that session. Did you figure whats the `sqlstate(08003)` error is?

Comment: I got a loop over Cities and I do a long process over each city. For now I solved the problem by adding a custom Reop(DAO) function, eager fetching all properties. But would have been nice if I did not had to do it.